# Better driver for Intel graphics card, Ubuntu 64bit

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card

I just installed **16.04 LTS [64bit]** version of **Linux Ubuntu**, but it says that my Graphics are: **Intel Sandybridge Mobile**, and the problem with that is that I cant open more than 2 windows of youtube videos in my browser, because temperature of my computer keeps rising like crazy, and I believe its because of this Sandybridge driver, my 2nd operating system is Windows 7 and everything is fine, and plus, its 32bit, so...is there a way to get better driver than this Sandybridge thing, because I think that my first display adapter [Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000] is the main one [and more important one] than Nvidia one, but now that this driver doesnt work like it should, Nvidia is the main one [which it shouldnt be, like it isnt on Windows also] and my computer overheats, am I wrong here maybe? Thanks

*Computer specs: Samsung laptop, Intel i3 (2.3ghz) processor, 4gb ram, 64bit based processor, 2 display adapters: 1. Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 2. NVIDIA GeForce GT 520MX (1gb each) 500gb hdd*

Maybe this pic might help [please ask if you need more information]

[image]

Comment: The Intel drive your using is the only one that exists for Linux.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand, but what do you think, is that the reason [bad drive] I am having problems with graphics?

Comment: Your machine overheating has nothing to do with your drivers.

Comment: @Ramhound it does in this case, since the driver is always using the higher power card, which generates more heat

Comment: You will probably get better expertise on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @CollDue96 Guess what happend there, so I had to ask here :D

Comment: They didn't answer???

Answer (score -1):

it looks like you are on a laptop using NVidia optimums technology (the laptop has the integrated intel gpu, and a dedicated NVidia one). Your laptop is likely overheating because it is now disregarding the lower powered intel one, and using the overkill NVidia gpu for everything.

The solution on Ubuntu for this is to download Bumblebee, a utility that acts as the NVidia driver should to tell the laptop when to use what chip intelligently. Follow instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation) for how to install it.

If you're running 14.04 or later, you'll just have to enable the Universe and Multiverse repositories, then run

> sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic

and reboot. For earlier versions of Ubuntu, or advanced options, see the link above.

Comment: [Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Blaine Finally someone with some constructive advice, thanks man, I'll tell ya how it goes...brb